# oracle 11g Thamaterialized views against another view

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

Good day,
Is it technically possible to create a materialized view against a another *view* in the master database (as opposed to a solid table)?
My DBA advises that oracle does not allow creation of materialized view logs against a view.  IMO a view is pretty much the same as a table, so it ought to be possible.
Has anyone ever done this successfully (Oracle 11g).

Comment: Have you tried it? If so did you get an error?

Comment: maybe your problem is more brad then you think. There are various ways how to synchronize materialized views and how to make it faster. Maybe your DBA has complains because of some fast refresh feature.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6003.htm#SQLRF54201) is pretty clear about this:

> **Restrictions on Master Tables of Materialized View Logs**
>
> The following restrictions apply to master tables of materialized view logs:
>
> - You cannot create a materialized view log for a temporary table or for a view.
> - You cannot create a materialized view log for a master table with a virtual column.

A view is not pretty much the same as a table. It's a stored query, so it has no storage and DML is only possible through instead-of triggers. It doesn't have the basis for noticing an underlying data change.

Just thinking about it, in order to support a view log - even for a simple single-table view - an update to the view's base table would have to check if there were any views; check if any of those had materialized view logs; and then work out if the change needed to be logged - which would mean executing each view's query and looking at the entire result set. Imagine doing that for *every* change to the underlying table. And then imagine a more complicated view query, with aggregates or multiple tables, etc.

You'd effectively be materialising the view query to decide whether was a change that needed to be logged, to update an actual materialized view. This is partly what actual materialized views do - stop you having to repeatedly re-execute an expensive view query by tracking changes on the master table(s).

You have to create the materialized view logs on the (normal) view's base tables.

Comment: Good day Alex, Appreciate your detailed reply.  Fully understood. Thank you.